# Flipping colors of image to its equivalent at the opposite side of spektrum

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

is there any way of flipping colors of image to its equivalent at the opposite side of spektrum. Like you have a color white, than it flips to black, blue to yellow etc. Thanks for answer.

Comment: How you define "opposite end of the spectrum"? One way may be to subtract each of the individual RGB components from 255 (if your colours are RGB format). That would give white -> black and blue -> yellow, I guess.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking with something like that, but I have no experience in this field so I rather asked, but thanks for reply :)

Comment: Well, I know a few things about colour scales but (unfortunately) little about C# and nothing about Unity. :-)

Comment: C# and GDI+ : Easily done (once you really know what you want) with a ColorMatrix.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple.

First, we need to discuss what Opposite Color is.

### In general,
Opposite Color means **complementary color**.

[Wiki, Complementary Color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_colors)

Please see the Wikipedia article for details.

In short, **complementary colors are two colors that, when mixed, result in a perfect white color**.

In RGB Color(0~255), white is (255, 255, 255).

For example, let's say you want to find the complementary color of **blue**. The RGB color of blue is **(0, 0, 255)** , so its complementary RGB value is **(255, 255, 0)**, **yellow**.

Let's express what i've said so far in UnityScript.

Note: unity use normalized range.(as 0-1)

```
    private Color GetOppositeColor(Color color)
    {
        return new Color(1f - color.r, 1f - color.g, 1f - color.g);
    }
```